# Sharepoint 2010 export groups and users from pre-production platform to production platform

Tags: groups, export

what is the best approach or is it manageable to export Sharepoint users and groups from a platform (pre-production ) to another platform (production)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/75e40c8b-6bfd-40ae-8af5-f1a0b3b17a2d

Hi,

For moving/exporting users and groups please follow these links:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/95331a32-9f87-46c5-a2d0-3034b2ccde69/

and

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions

Wali Systems Inc. (http://walisystemsinc.com) Hire certified virtual SharePoint assistants/developers!